# Retrieve and filter Subcollections with VueJS and Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to retrieve and filter data from my Subcollections with VueJs from Cloud Firestore. The Output works well, with

```
db.collection('deliveryservice').doc('0GKIOX8LHdUpxo0ZQrsY').collection('product')
  .get().then(querySnapshot => {
              querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
```

i tried to filter products by using the .where statement, without any success. Console said

> a.collection(...).doc(...).where is not a function

The code i tried is

```
db.collection('deliveryservice').doc('0GKIOX8LHdUpxo0ZQrsY').collection('product')
  .where('product_id', '==', to.params.product_id)
            .get().then(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
```

Comment: What's the problem when you are using the second query?

Comment: That error message doesn't seem to match any of the code you're showing here.  Could you go back and check that everything matches?